# Multiple Table Online Play

Tags: online, tournament, poker-strategy, sit-and-go

When playing online, I have tried a few sessions of 9 or 6 player SnG where I will join about 10 - 15 tournaments at the same time.

It's hard to keep up and sometimes I even get sat out (could be a blessing though because sometimes I come back and I'm already in the money just from sitting out).

I have not really been able to gauge whether this is a better strategy or not.  I have read that this is a good way to eliminate the dead money in your bankroll and not get hung up or emotionally attached to one particular table.

I do see the benefit in that by trying it out a few times, but I'm not sure if it's the best way to go.

Has anyone had any experience doings lots of tables all at once in online play?

Any Pros and Cons to doing it this way as opposed to just one or two tables at a time?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I don't know about SnG specifically but the more tables you add, the more robotic your play and more weak in general, that will lead to less winrate. There are certainly guys that multi-table 24 or even more (!) tables but they didn't end up that easy. If you can't cope as you say with 10, the next step is to lower down a bit, _not a lot_. Since you can play max ~10, try 8 or 6. Find your sweet spot where you can _breath_ between plays without feeling _you run for it_ and still maintain a good quality and winrate.

Comment: "a good way to eliminate the dead money in your bankroll" wait... what?

Comment: @popovitsj Statistically, your going to lose a certain number of tourneys.  Its just not possible to win every time.  Those losses are dead money.   If you play a ton of tables at once, getting through the dead money is not so time consuming.   I dunno, just something I heard.

Comment: I guess the thinking is.. if you play 6 tables one at a time and it takes you 6 hours and you only place in the money on 1/3rd of them (the odds of winning),  then you will have burned 4 dead money tourneys and cashed on two good money tourneys in six hours.   Now if you play 3 tables at once, for a total of 18 tables,  then you still spend 6 hours, but you burn up 3x as much dead money, saving time, increasing profits, theoretically.

Comment: I now kind of understand what you mean, but this reasoning is flawed. In poker, results-oriented thinking is bad. You should always strive to maximize your expected value (EV). It may be hard to get your head around it, but the actual result of the tournament is not relevant from a strategy point of view.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you slowly build up to this amount of tables rather than diving into it all at once. If you are timing out like you say then this is a sign that you are playing way too many tables. You should play the amount right now that allows you to make good quality decisions but not get bored. Then add one at a time as you get used to it. gl!

Comment: This is the best answer IMO

Answer (score 0):

You are abusing the term 'dead money'. Dead money is used to describe the entree fees from players who have virtually no chance of winning the tournament.

If you are a profitable player, your entree fee is never dead money. Whether you actually cash in the tournament doesn't come in to this.

This boils down to a certain mindset required in playing profitable poker: actual results are not important and should not be taken into account when analyzing your play. Instead, you need to focus on maximizing your expected value (EV), not your actual profits.

With regards to your question, this means that you should keep adding tables as long as it contributes to your EV. With every table you add, your EV per table is expected to go down, because you can devote a smaller part of your attention to making the right decisions.

However, the total EV might very well go up. For example: let's say that 1-tabling, your EV is +$5/hr, and adding 1 table will make your EV drop to $4/hr. In this case 2-tabling will earn +$8/hr (2x $4/hr).